# Hive Update : Null Pointer Exception while using If statement

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have table in hive in which i have to update certain records. I am using hive 0.13 version. I did bit of googling and found that i can use If-Else statement with insert overwrite for doing this but after running a query it is throwing null pointer exception.

Here is my Employee table:

```
1       emp1  
2       emp2    
3       emp3    
4       emp4   
5       emp5
```

I created another table employee_incr with same schema as employee and ran this query to get updated records.

```
insert overwrite table employee_incr select employee.ename,if(employee.id="1",12,employee.id ) as employee.id from employee;
```

Here is trace from Hive.

```
 Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
2015-07-27 16:26:42,086 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(108)) - <PERFLOG method=compile from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-07-27 16:26:42,111 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(108)) - <PERFLOG method=parse from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-07-27 16:26:42,115 INFO  [main]: parse.ParseDriver (ParseDriver.java:parse(185)) - Parsing command: insert overwrite table employee_incr select employee.ename,if(employee.id="1",12,employee.id ) as employee.id from employee
2015-07-27 16:26:42,332 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(547)) - FAILED: NullPointerException null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regularBody(HiveParser.java:37646)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:36884)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:36760)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1338)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:980)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1045)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:916)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:906)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

2015-07-27 16:26:42,333 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(135)) - </PERFLOG method=compile start=1437994602086 end=1437994602333 duration=247 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-07-27 16:26:42,333 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(108)) - <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-07-27 16:26:42,333 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(135)) - </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1437994602333 end=1437994602333 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-07-27 16:26:42,337 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(108)) - <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2015-07-27 16:26:42,337 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(135)) - </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1437994602337 end=1437994602337 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
```

Any help?

Comment: from your question i can see that your employee(2 cols) , employee_incr(2 cols) are same. but in the ERROR log @ 2015-07-24 09:55:05,426 ERROR [main] , Select is having 3 columns where as your employee_incr has 2 columns to accomodate. means you are trying to push 3cols into 2 cols . plz check

Comment: Hi Vijay, by mistake i pasted wrong log. Now i took recent log and updated in my question.